# Why do we need multiple iptables?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, iptables

In `man iptables` there are 4 tables defined: `filter`, `mangle`, `nat`, `raw`. And many of them have the same predefined chain. For instance, `nat` and `mangle` both have `OUTPUT` chain.

The question is why do we need different tables with the same chain?

Comment: you assume that the nat output chain is the same as the mangle output chain

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=iptables+chart&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: @JaromandaX from my current understanding the chain with the same name are shared across the tables

Comment: run `iptables -t nat -L OUTPUT` ... then do the same for tables mangle, filter and raw ... now, if you have some rules, are they the same in all for tables? I take it you ignored jsotola's comment